# Tensor product of bounded analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, banach-spaces, tensor-products, hardy-spaces

Let $H^\infty(\mathbb{D})$ denote the set of functions holomorphic and bounded on $\mathbb{D} = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| < 1\}$.
Conseqently, $H^\infty(\mathbb{D}^n)$ denotes the set of bounded holomorphic functions on the polydisk $\mathbb{D}^n = \mathbb{D} \times \ldots \times \mathbb{D}$.

With the norm $\|f\|_{H^\infty(\mathbb{D}^n)} := \sup_{z \in \mathbb{D}^n} |f(z)|$ these sets become Banach spaces (and are called Hardy-spaces).

Is it true, that 
$$H^\infty(\mathbb{D}) \otimes H^\infty(\mathbb{D}) = H^\infty(\mathbb{D}^2),$$
where $\otimes$ denotes the completion with respect to the $H^\infty(\mathbb{D}^2)$-norm?

Thank you for any hints or references!

Comment: So in other words, you want to know if a bounded holomorphic function on a 2-polydisk can be written as a limit of sum of products of holomorphic functions in one variable, each of which are bounded function on the unit disk?

Comment: Do elements of $H^\infty(\mathbb{D}^2)$ have a Taylor series expansion? That would provide a positive answer to your question, no?

Comment: @Braindead I don't think so. The Taylor series of $f\in H^\infty(\mathbb{D}^k)$ does in general not converge uniformly on the whole polydisk - that is the case only for functions that have a continuous extension to the closed polydisk - and thus from the partial sums of the Taylor series you would not obtain a $H^\infty$ approximation.